# using column minimums within an apply function

Tags: r

I have an apply function:

```
flow.index<-apply(dt_matrix,c(1,2),function(x) (1-x)/x)
```

`dt_matrix` is sort of large (500k elements) and is organized by column. This function works as written, but the "1" in `(1-x)/x` should be the minimum value of the column that the apply function is working in. I.e. if the value being applied to is 2, and the minimum value for the column that includes the value being applied is 1, then the apply function should return `(1-2)/2)` = -0.5.

I'm guessing the answer is simple but I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: If you pass c(1,2) as the second argument to `apply` you are not doing a column-wise procedure.

Comment: I meant to apply to the entire matrix. The trouble I'm having is getting the function that I'm applying (to the entire matrix) to call the minimum of the column that I'm working in.

Comment: You should *never* use `apply` when working on columns (only on rows), it is very inefficient and you should use `lapply` instead. But there are many better options such `data.table` and `dplyr` packages. I would suggest that you provide a small example of your data and the desired output if you want to receive good answers

Comment: The code offered below will get applied to "the entire matrix" but it gets there by passing a column at a time which allows calculation of the `min`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 flow.index<-apply(dt_matrix, 2 , function(x) (min(x)-x)/x)
```

Comment: That apply function worked! The sapply doesn't appear to. Thanks!